# Relationship fields in 2.7 as URLs

Tags: ee2, relationships

Trying to link to pages as "Related Articles". Here is my code. The template is used to display the articles. My text, "Related Articles" is not showing either. Using EE 2.7. Any help is appreciated.

```
    <div class="sixteen columns mainContent redTop boxShadow">
    {exp:channel:entries category="{embed:pageCat}" limit="1"}


        <div class="text eleven columns alpha">

            <h1 class="blue borderBottom">{news_title}</h1>
            <span class="date orange">{entry_date format="%F %j, %Y"}</span>
            {if news_image}
                {news_image var_prefix="file"}
                <div class="pageImage right"><img src="{file:url}" alt="{file:alt_text}"></div>
                {/news_image}
            {/if}
            {news_text}

            {related_articles}
                {if related_articles}
                Related Articles:
                <ul>
                {/if}
                <li><a href="{site_url}/news/industry/{last_segment}">{related_articles:title}</a></li>
                {if related_articles:count == related_articles:total_results}
                </ul>
                {/if}
            {/related_articles}             

        </div>

        {embed="includes/zipSearch"}

<div class="five columns sidebar right alpha">
    <div class="box boxShadow blueTop sideNav">{exp:channel:entries category="11"}
        <h4>Spread Awareness:</h4>
        {!--exp:navee:nav nav_title="main-site-nav" selected_class="selected"  parent_selected_class="selected" start_nav_with_kids_of_selected="true" start_nav_from_parent="true" start_nav_from_parent_depth="1" only_display_children_of_selected="true"--}
        {exp:navee:nav nav_title="main-site-nav" selected_class="selected" start_node="/spread-awareness/" start_nav_from_parent_depth="2" only_display_children_of_selected="true"}
    </div>

    {if "{related_video:count}" != ""}
    <div class="box boxShadow orangeTop">
        <div class="youtubeLink">
            <iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/{related_video}{related_video:video}{/related_video}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    {/if}
</div><!--end sidebar-->
    {/exp:channel:entries}
    </div><!--end mainContent-->
```

Comment: I'm no expert, but it seems you're using the {if} conditional wrong. I'm not sure {if related_articles} is proper syntax, and I see you are using {/if} followed by another {/if}. In my experience, if plain text isn't being rendered within a variable tag pair, it's because the tag pair is wrong. How is your current markup rendering as source?

Comment: 88mpg is correct. Remove that `{if related_articles}` check. The {related_articles} already acts as an if-check. If there are articles, it'll show them. if there aren't any articles, it won't show anything between the open and close.

Answer (score 1):

From the point that you probably always have related articles, you might try this:

```
Related Articles:    
<ul>
{related_articles}  
  <li><a href="{site_url}/news/industry/{last_segment}">{related_articles:title}</a></li>
{/related_articles} 
<ul>
```

Comment: I think that `<li><a href="{related_articles:page_url}">{related_articles:title}</a></li>` will work too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution (hope this helps someone else):

```
                {related_articles}
                    {if related_articles:count == 1}
                    <h2 class="blue borderBottom">Related Articles:</h2>
                    <ul>
                    {/if}
                    <p><a href="{path="/spread-awareness/news/"}/{related_articles:url_title}">{related_articles:title}</a></p>
                    {if related_articles:count == related_articles:total_results}
                    </ul>
                    {/if}
                {/related_articles}
```

Comment: Better yet: [title_permalink](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#title-permalink)! `{related_articles:title_permalink="spread-awareness/news"}`.